# vb6 deployment with crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, vb6, crystal-reports-xi

I am looking for ways how to deploy my vb6 project with crystal report XI to no success. I have read forums and all I got is confusion. When I deploy My setup to client's computer the report is not working. I have read that you need crystal report merge modules and I can confirm that there a merge module in my computer with my crystal report

I have tried

1. Package and deployment wizard - there are so many crystal report dll missing.I tried manually adding the dll but it is not working
2. install shield 2010 - it seems there many library missing even I even with the use of merge module. It does not let me compile
3. setup factory 9 - it seems that there is no merge module functionality.

here is a sample code

```
Dim sampleApp       As CRAXDDRT.Application
Dim sampleReport    As CRAXDDRT.Report
Dim sqlQuerry       As String

Set sampleApp = New CRAXDDRT.Application
Set sampleReport = sampleApp.OpenReport(App.Path & "\custom_reports\report1.rpt")
sqlQuerry = "select * from membermst"

Set dbconnect1 = New SqlConnectionCLS
dbconnect1.openSQLConnection
dbconnect1.sqlCommand.CommandText = sqlQuerry
Set rstRecord = dbconnect1.sqlCommand.Execute

sampleReport.DiscardSavedData
sampleReport.Database.SetDataSource rstRecord, 3, 1
CRViewer1.ReportSource = sampleReport
CRViewer1.ViewReport
```

here are my vb6 preferences

[image]

Am I missing something?
Can somebody guide me how to deploy vb6 application with crystal report.

Comment: Merge modules should do, at least for CR11. Is there merge module for craxddrt? This is not usual redistributable component, craxdrt is more common. For older Crystal9, we resulted in adding all required files into Installshield project - there are many of these, about 30 or 40. And we had to create reg file to merge at build, quite nasty :( If you install files seprately, then you have to install these into correct folder too; merge module should do that automatically.

Comment: I changed craxddrt.dll to craxdrt.dll. but the install shield still detect the craxdrt.dll missing. Is my code at fault here? what dll should I use in my code in crystal report X1 r2. I'm at lost here thx

Comment: Can you remove dependencies check for your application executable in Installshield? What merge modules you have included? (Sorry I don't know about CR11 merge modules much.)

Comment: We have an CRXI installer compiled using a Visual Studio 2008 setup project. We integrated this in Inno Setup and it is working. You are welcome to share this, but I am not aware of the conditions that SO has to allow such an individual support scenario.

Comment: Now I realize that the problem is the "keycode" is not allowed to null when using cr115_net_ 2005 on merging module. I tried using install shield 2010 and that is the error. If i remembered correctly I activated my crystal report and even registered my product for activation. now why the heck it needs keys code if I already inserted it. I can use the crystal report normally but when on merging error it is not.